# RegEx Find all matches in the group

Tags: regex, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a below string:

```
can't access email and password
```

If I use the below expression, it will find just one match and return it.

```
.*(access|test|rental|email|password).*
```

What to do if I want to get `access`, `email` and `password` all matched and capture them all in the same group (perhaps separated by comma)?

In Python, I can use `findall()` which will return a list of all matches. I am not sure how to do this in Pentaho.

Comment: Remove `.*` from both sides

Comment: You can’t match input in one group that isn’t contiguous - regex can’t skip over or ignore input while capturing a group.

Comment: In pdi, you can use javascript to get this result.